# How to make jQuery hide custom lightbox

Tags: jquery, class, lightbox

I have created a custom lightbox with the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="lightbox">
    <img src="thumbnail.jpg" />
    <div class="box">
        <img class="boximage" src="full-image.jpg" />
        <p>Caption</p>
        <div class="close"><p>x</p></div>
    </div>
</a>
```

The following JavaScript opens the correct individual full `.boximage` class image when that individual thumbnail with `.lightbox` class is clicked on.

```
$('.lightbox').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.box, .boximage').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Previously I had some JavaScript which works to close the lightbox when you click on the close x.

```
$('.close').click(function(){
    $('.box, .boximage').css('display', 'none');
});
```

But I can't seem to get the close lightbox to work.

How do I make the close functionality work?

Comment: What happens when you try to close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BhojendraNepal has correctly pointed out that the key is to use `event.stopPropagation()`. In addition to that, if you need to have multiple such elements on a page, you want to keep the `context` of the click as follows:

```
$('.close').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('.box').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```js
$('.lightbox').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.box, .boximage').css('display', 'block');
}); 
$('.close').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('.box').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1. <a href="#" class="lightbox">
  <img src="thumbnail.jpg">
  <div class="box">
    <img class="boximage" src="full-image.jpg"/>
    <p>Caption</p>
    <div class="close">
      <p>x</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
<br>2. 
<a href="#" class="lightbox">
  <img src="thumbnail.jpg">
  <div class="box">
    <img class="boximage" src="full-image.jpg"/>
    <p>Caption 2</p>
    <div class="close">
      <p>x</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
<br>3. 
<a href="#" class="lightbox">
  <img src="thumbnail.jpg">
  <div class="box">
    <img class="boximage" src="full-image.jpg"/>
    <p>Caption 3</p>
    <div class="close">
      <p>x</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation) which prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$('.close').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   $('.box, .boximage').css('display', 'none');
});
```

As you're binding click event in lightbox and clicking on close button applies to lightbox to be clicked also. So, you need to prevent bubbling up the tree.

Comment: Thanks very much Bhojendra!

Is there also a way to make it close when you click anywhere on the page?

Comment: then bind click function to body.